# How to get a Dehn-twist presentation of  a periodic map of a Riemann surface?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, mapping-class-groups

Let $f:S\to S$ be a given periodic map of order $n$, and  $(m_i,\lambda_i, \sigma_i)$ be the valency of the multiple point $p_i$ of $f$ ( $i=1,\cdots,r$ ).

A classical result says such $f$ is isotopic  to a product of Dehn twists. 
It is trivial when $n=1$. Now we assume that $n>1$. I want to know how to get  such a Dehn twist presentation.

---

For a pseudo-periodic map,  a similar  Dehn twist presentation  implies Picard-Lefschetz formula of the  monodromy of a singular  fiber (semistable or non-semistable).   In fact, I wish to comupte the monodromy  of a non-semistable fiber.

---

For hyperelliptic periodic maps, Ishzaka provided a method.

Comment: How is the map given in the first place?


Comment: The above question is answered in some detail by my answer to the following:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/142365/mapping-class-group-of-a-surface/142367

Comment: So, I am voting to close.

Comment: @SamNead: Do you think it is reasonable to close an old question as a duplicate of a much newer question?

Comment: @Stefan: Well, the alternative is to cut-and-paste my answer.  But I thought that would be poor form.